# Can you identify this trailing plant from my old home?

Tags: identification, vines, outdoor

It was an evergreen climber in our front porch back in the 1990s. We never took photos of it directly, but it has been in the background of our photos (so excuse the **low quality image**). The plant produced yellow flowers from autumn to winter.

The photo was taken in Amman, Jordan.

[image]

Comment: It won't be Hedera colchica if the flowers were yellow. What did the flowers look like and was the plant in a pot or in the ground when you had it previously? Any fragrance?

Comment: @Bamboo The flowers are slightly apparent in the image (bottom centre), and they seem to about to bloom. I just remember small yellow flowers. Nothing too specific. The plant was in ground and, as you can see, it was a vine. I don't remember any scent. Any idea about it being Senecio Angulatus though?

Comment: From the foliage, Senecio angulatus  is a strong possibility if you think the flowers are similar to what you recall. The only thing is, I'd have expected it to be much bigger and widespread if it was planted in the ground - unless it was cut back regularly? Though perhaps the photo doesn't show all of the growth...

Comment: I cannot recall cut backs, but maybe my mother would have cut it back. I really don't remember. The plant was placed in a raised garden bed and it did trail to the right onto our porch door. Perhaps it was a young plant? Maybe that's why it wasn't widespread?

Comment: E.Groeg Senecio sure looks like your plant.  Yeah, don't plant it in the ground until you learn more about it's weed classification.  Surprised I didn't look this plant up first...remember, the fact that it is a weed means it will be a great survivor and produce well.  Just cut the flowers off before they go to seed and you shall be set.

Answer (score 1):

This plant belongs to the family [Cucurbitaceae](https://nph.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/nph.16015) which includes:
 Cucumber Gourds Watermelon

Plants in this family are sprawling vines that typically have tendrils, and all cucurbits have bright yellow flowers, except for the bottle gourd.

I suspect this is a Cucumber vine from the leaves in the photo, although it might be one of the many [Gourds](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gourds+vine) that belong to this same family

I doubt they are watermelon as the leaves are too small, could be a zucchini, luffa.....

Cucumber given the shape of the leaves 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look up Honeysuckle: Lonicera...[Lonicera](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/types-honeysuckle-vines-37386.html)

It is tough to ID anything from pictures.  We can only do our best.  Bamboo is the ID Queen.  I like to insert different ideas to help double check.

Could you take a picture of the 'wimpy' flower.  I've tried to see the flower you are discussing but haven't been able to...and the flower would help tremendously.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Though the flowers did not look that showy and 'fancy'.

Comment: That is the problem.  This looks like the north side of your home, less light, possibly too much nitrogen in your fertilizer.  Nitrogen that is higher in percentage than Phosphorous and Potassium causes high vegetative growth and low to no reproductive growth.  The plant looks oh so healthy and vigorous and very dark green which is one of the signs of excess Nitrogen.  Whatever plant it is I would plant it in the ground right where it sits.  Dump soil and plant in a hole exactly the size of the root ball.  No deeper than original root ball depth.  Then I would make a gorgeous...

Comment: ...gorgeous trellis against that wall.  One with hinges so one can paint and maintain aeration between plant and home.  It would sit out away from the wall 8 to 12 inches.  I always made squares out of lap jointed 2X2s for the pattern.  Quit fertilizing for 3 months and then use an all purpose extended release BALANCED fertilizer.  Use HALF of what the directions tell you. In fact, I'd go 1/4 of the directions because your plants are in the shade. Most of us can only imagine what it must be like to live in the Mediterranean area. Oh so nice...the temp here is 11 degrees F below zero. Ugh.

Comment: I'll bet that plant and others have rooted well into the soil below the pot.  You might have to break the pot to plant the plant in the soil.  You most certainly can wait and leave well enough alone.  The chemistry of the soil of that plant needs to be changed to get it to flower I am thinking.

Comment: Thanks for some handy info. You're right, it is tough to ID anything from pictures. The leaves of my plant were glossy and smooth. This plant here has hairy, 'rougher' leaves. Btw, my plant was on a garden bed. It wasn't potted.

Comment: It's easy to identify if you have seen them before. Although that is a very grainy photo,  so only someone with experience of the plant family would spot it! Without your clues it would have been even more difficult.